# http command-line from in-browser network tracing

Tags: debugging, http, curl, wget

I am debugging a web API — currently using the Firefox network panel, Ctrl-Shift-K in recent releases — and I would like to convert requests to a command line (wget or curl) which I can more easily customise. Is there a tool to do that?

Comment: What information do you need as you can simply open the URI from curl. But if you need session and cookie information it's another ball game

Comment: An alternative http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ which lets you capture, edit, replay & build request

Comment: @tryme My requests currently have post parameters, and either cookies or http authentication. This is for convenience and more streamlined debugging, so copy-pasting is no good.